# Getting item from array (index check)

Tags: c#

In the following piece of code (c# cookbook), what is the purpose of checking if index is greater than or equal to zero?

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Get an item from the class
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="index">the index of the item to get</param>
 /// <returns>an item of type object</returns>
 public object GetItem(int index)
 {
   if (index >= this.Items.Length &&
   index >= 0)
   throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
   return this.Items[index];
 }
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. And this is not adding, this is checking and accessing an array element. This is done natively, I don't get why would you reinvent the wheel by doing this explicitly.

Comment: This doesn't look like a place where an item is added to an array. It looks more like a method of returning the item at a given index. In this case checking if the index is in range is appropriate.

Comment: I think there needs to be more context, this doesn't quite make sense. You wouldn't throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if the index was equal to or greater than 0.... surely

Comment: Can you reindent your code?

Comment: [Throws c# cookbook in waste basket.]

Comment: Stupid question: are you sure this is the code as written in the book?

Comment: The check if its greater or equal to 0 is pointless since checking against the length would encompass this

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an error in the code. I think who ever wrote this, inverted the sign :)

If index is less than zero, you would index your `this.Items` with a negative value. That is not permitted...

Comment: But the check is if the index is more than or equal to the length, which is fine. The second part is more than or equal to 0, so if the index is within  permitted range, throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The only purpose would be to have different exceptions for values that are above and below the allowed index range. If the index is negative, the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` will not be thrown, so instead an `IndexOutOfRangeException` will be thrown on the next line.

The code doesn't look correct. It would make a lot more sense if the code checked the upper and lower bounds of the index:

```
if (index >= this.Items.Length || index < 0) {
  throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
}
return this.Items[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if (length <= index || index < 0)
```

What the OP posted is utter nonsense.

Furthermore, assuming length is a property of some type of array, the right-most expression in the OP's post will always be true, so it's a waste of KB's...

And for the sake of sharing, since expressions are evaluated left-to-right, put your most obvious exclusions on the left; as soon as one fails as it's encountered, no more will be evaluated.

Consider:

```
bool b = false;

if (!b || a == 2)
    // a == 2 will never be evaluated.

// More useful, real-world:
if (myData != null && myData.Satisfies.SomeOtherCondition)
    // if myData is null, the program doesn't bother with the rest...
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code:

```
if (index >= this.Items.Length && index >= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

return this.Items[index];
```

This doesn't make sense to me, because you are throwing an error, if you have the correct index..

It should be:

```
if (index >= this.Items.Length || index < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

return this.Items[index];
```

The purpose of this is to make sure that you don't give the wrong index to the array and throwing an unknown error.

But then again, I wouldn't do this. I would optimise it further. It will already throw an error if the index is out of range, so it doesn't seem advantageous throwing the same error before the underlying code will.

Comment: `index >= this.Items.Length` ...  The check for a valid index would be `index < Items.Length && index > 0`.  However, he shouldn't be allowing negative numbers...

Comment: What is wrong with that? I can't see the issue. My code is correct.

Comment: *"because you are throwing an error, if you have the correct index.."* - If `index` is greater than or equal to the length of the array, it will also be greater than or equal to 0, but you've got a bad index.  You are correct to check for `< 0` and add the OR, now the entire check is doing the right thing, but I was commenting on your statement that the initial check would throw on a good index, which it never would.

Comment: To be fair I keep reading it, and I can't understand that line - I'm probably overthinking it... Either way it makes so much more sense to do my suggested way but I still don't see any reason what so ever if the code is already prepared to throw an error. I much prefer to let it throw and handle that error further up the pipeline

Comment: Well, I agree there, especially considering that he is throwing the exact same error that the collection would throw.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the right syntax would be something like that:

```
  if ((index < Items.GetLowerBound(0)) || (index > Items.GetUpperBound(0)))
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

  return this.Items[index];
```

Since array in C# doesn't necessary *zero-based* one and you can expect (at least in nightmare) to run into monster like that:

```
var myUglyArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[] { 12 }, new int[] { 1 });
```

However, such arrays are rare avises and not *CLS-compliant*, that's why if your assemply is CLS-complaint

```
[assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]
```

you can simplify the check into

```
  if ((index < 0) || (index >= Items.Length))
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

  return this.Items[index];
```